# SPARK DataFrame: Remove MAX value in a group

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

My data is like:

```
id | val
---------------- 
a1 |  10
a1 |  20
a2 |  5
a2 |  7
a2 |  2
```

I am trying to delete row that has MAX(val) in the group if I group on "id".

Result should be like:

```
id | val
---------------- 
a1 |  10
a2 |  5
a2 |  2
```

I am using SPARK DataFrame and SQLContext. I need some way like:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM jsontable WHERE (id, val) NOT IN (SELECT is,MAX(val) from jsontable GROUP BY id)");
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using dataframe operations and Window functions. Assuming you have your data in the dataframe `df1`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val maxOnWindow = max(col("val")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("id")))
val df2 = df1
  .withColumn("max", maxOnWindow)
  .where(col("val") < col("max"))
  .select("id", "val")
```

In Java, the equivalent would be something like:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.Window;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

Column maxOnWindow = max(col("val")).over(Window.partitionBy("id"));
DataFrame df2 = df1
    .withColumn("max", maxOnWindow)
    .where(col("val").lt(col("max")))
    .select("id", "val");
```

Here's a nice article about window functions: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I am trying your approach now. Just wondering is it better than "join" approach?

Comment: @user3802925 As your data is originally in a DataFrame, this approach avoids converting it to RDD, which is already a gain both in performance and in code readability. However, I think the actual performance difference between both approaches will depend on your data and it would require some tests to make conclusions.

Comment: @user3802925: Sorry, I hadn't seen the join version with DataFrame. In this case, only my second statement stands.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the Java implementation of Mario's scala code:

```java
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(input);
DataFrame dfMaxRaw = df.groupBy("id").max("val");
DataFrame dfMax = dfMaxRaw.select(
    dfMaxRaw.col("id").as("max_id"), dfMaxRaw.col("max(val)").as("max_val")
);
DataFrame combineMaxWithData = df.join(dfMax, df.col("id")
    .equalTo(dfMax.col("max_id")));
DataFrame finalResult = combineMaxWithData.filter(
    combineMaxWithData.col("id").equalTo(combineMaxWithData.col("max_id"))
        .and(combineMaxWithData.col("val").notEqual(combineMaxWithData.col("max_val"))) 
);
```

Comment: looks good, albeit a bit verbose, but that's expected from Java :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do this using RDD and a more Scala-flavored approach:

```scala
// Let's first get the data in key-value pair format
val data = sc.makeRDD( Seq( ("a",20), ("a", 1), ("a",8), ("b",3), ("b",10), ("b",9) ) )

// Next let's find the max value from each group
val maxGroups = data.reduceByKey( Math.max(_,_) )

// We join the max in the group with the original data
val combineMaxWithData = maxGroups.join(data)

// Finally we filter out the values that agree with the max
val finalResults = combineMaxWithData.filter{ case (gid, (max,curVal)) => max != curVal }.map{ case (gid, (max,curVal)) => (gid,curVal) }


println( finalResults.collect.toList )
>List((a,1), (a,8), (b,3), (b,9))
```

Comment: I have not done any Spark on Java ... There should be equivalents to Java for each of these APIs. It might not be that hard to do the translation. The main ideas should apply.

Comment: Thanks Marios! Below is the Java implementation I had with some modification on join, where I join using a key instead of full cartesian join.